# Bash Script not prompt for user input

Tags: bash, gitlab, hook

I am running the following script as gitlab pre-receive hook, but it never prompt for user input, and "Please type yes or no" never showed on the screen. Any suggestion to fix the issue? Thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read oldrev newrev branch

if [ "$oldrev" != "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]; then
    
    #do something

    read -p "Please type yes or no" ans
    if [ "$ans" = "yes" ]; then
        #do something
    fi

fi
```

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: The first `read` doesn't have a prompt. So it's just waiting for you to enter 3 words.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I'm running the script as gitlab pre-receive hook. The first `read` reads commits and branch in gitlab, so I don't need to enter 3 words.

Comment: The hook's standard input isn't connected to the terminal. git passes a list of references that are being pushed to the script via standard input.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!!!